# Extra pixel on mouse over in Chrome. Double scrollbar

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've got this nasty pixel problem on a 'mouse over' in Chrome (IE en Firefox ok).

This is the site [www.joetz.be](http://www.joetz.be) (pick a region first)

When you hover an image you get a double scrollbar. But only from the second row. The first row is ok.
When you look at the second column you see there is een extra pixel (dark icon bar) that disappears when you hover it.

[image]

Allready tried a lot of things but can't figure out where it goes wrong.

Anyone any idea?

Comment: can you be more specific, I've tried all regions and hovered on many offers (only thing with images I found) on all regions, no problem in Chrome :)

Comment: i can't see a problem - using chrome 47.0.2526.106 m

Comment: I've got the same verison. Test when the page is fully loaded.

Comment: Chrome v 47.0.2526.106, page is fully loaded, but I cannot see double scrollbars, nor the pixel. Is it always the second row of blocks, independent of the region? do you have some plugins in chrome that might interfere?

Comment: @wellagain it are all the rows except the first one, independent of the region. Never thought about a plug-in. I'll check it. thx

Comment: @wellagain It was a plug-in (pinterest). Now everything is ok.
Thanks for the very usefull tip!

Answer (score 2):

The problem was caused by a Pinterest plug-in in Chrome.

Thanks to @wellagain for the tip!